# Sed - replace variable help

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace a version within multiple files.

This is easy to do for a string that has no spaces.

.env contents:

```
VERSION=1.15.10
```

The following works fine:

```
sed -i "/^VERSION=/s/=.*/=2.0.0/" .env
```

I'm having issues with the replacing the following string:

```
<server name="SYSTEM_APP_VERSION" value="0.15.1"/>
```

with

```
<server name="SYSTEM_APP_VERSION" value="2.0.0"/>
```

The number within value="" varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$ INPUT=2.0.0
$ sed "/SYSTEM_APP_VERSION/ s/value=\".*\"/value=\"$INPUT\"/" tt

<server name="SYSTEM_APP_VERSION" value="2.0.0"/>
```